# how come typeof !function(){} is boolean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I was trying to understand the code in http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html and stuck with following snippet

```
typeof function(){} // "function"
typeof !function(){}  // "boolean"
```

I like to understand why it become boolean after adding !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The point of `!` is to convert a value into a boolean `true` or `false` (and invert it).

> Logical NOT Operator ( ! )
>
> The production UnaryExpression : ! UnaryExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let oldValue be ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)).
> 3. If oldValue is true, return false
> 4. Return true.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9

Answer (score 1):

The `!` symbol converts a value into `true` or `false`.

In your case the value is a `function(){}`. So when `!` is placed in front of it then it changes that to `false`.

Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/zz722703%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator always returns a boolean, and since `function(){}` is not a falsy<sup>*</sup> (false-like) value, you are merely returning the boolean inverse of it, which is `false` since the value is not falsy.

[Here's a good overview of truthy/falsy values I found.](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

For example, you can try these out in your JS console:

```
console.log(5) //5
console.log(!5) //false, because 5 is not null

console.log("hello") //hello
console.log(!"hello") //false, because "hello" is not null

var fun = function() { console.log("Yay") }
console.log(fun) //Shows the function definition
console.log(!fun) //false, because the value of fun is not null
```

Comment: "not null" in your answer should be replaced by "not a falsey value".  null is not the only falsey value - there are many.

Answer (score -2):

hmmm... is it truthy / falsy game???

```
typeof typeof function(){} // "string"
if("") {alert('truthy')} else {alert('falsy');}  // falsy
typeof !"" // "boolean"
```

Am I understood this correctly?

Comment: Just the answers of @Quentin, Rahul Tripathy. SO community is so fast. thanks. After posting above only I saw other answers. Leaving my stupid answer as it is so that other learn from my mistake.